# jQuery show div loading onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need your advice with my jQuery on click, show div loading before page loaded. I tested the code, but the div loading is not show.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(".taskss3").click(function(evt)
{
    $('#status_random').show();
    var get_uid = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#randomdiv").load("load_auto.php?uid="+ get_uid)
    {
        $('#status_random').hide();
        $('#randomdiv').show();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="status_random"></div>
<div id="randomdiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
#status_random
{
background: url('../../assets/images/processing.gif');
height: 24px;
width: 24px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the callback

```
$(".taskss3").click(function (evt) {
    $('#status_random').show();
    var get_uid = this.id;

    $("#randomdiv").load("load_auto.php?uid=" + get_uid, function () {
        //do this in the load callback
        $('#status_random').hide();
        $('#randomdiv').show();
    })

});
```

In your code, you are hiding the loader as soon as the `load()` is called without waiting for the loading to complete.